# Using a route helper for a controller without a model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing, view-helpers

I have a controller `JaxDataController` for responding to ajax requests which has no associated model.

It has a single routes.rb entry `match "/jaxdata/:shape_set_id" => "jax_data#fetch"`

I'd like to include the path to this model within a .js.coffee.erb view elsewhere in my app. Are there  any routing helpers available for this? Failing that, where should i declare a routing helper to be used in any view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify the `:as` option in your route, it will create helpers for that route. Thus:

```
 match "/jaxdata/:shape_set_id" => "jax_data#fetch", :as => :jaxdata
```

You should then be able to refer to `jaxdata_path` in your views.

See section 3.6 of this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html